# Why Regression should only be done on Non-Stationary data points?

Tags: regression, pca

I am working through a course on PCA and Factor analysis, where the example is to perform regression on stock prices, with an objective to predict the stock prices.

The author claims, that we need to predict '**Returns**' instead of '**Prices**', as Prices are **Stationary**, and Regression always needs to be performed on **NonStationary** or **Trending** Data.

The explanation of above is out of the scope of the course.

Can anyone please share an intuition why does the said argument hold true?

Comment: @SmallChess I have already asked this to be moved to stats.stackexchange.com Need a moderator help or votes from folks with 300+rep

Comment: No. Move to quant.stackexchange. They are professional anything like stock price.

Comment: Not sure if you got the quote right. This paper says that `prices are non-stationary, while returns are generally regarded as stationary` http://www.econ.ohio-state.edu/dejong/note1.pdf I personally find that probably neither is stationary. You can do regression on anything, but in the case of financial time series, your estimator is not necessarily BLUE because some assumptions of OLS don't necessarily hold.

Comment: @WillGu I confirmed again. It says 'Prices are stationary, Returns are Non-stationary'. I also don't understand the terms 'BLUE' and 'OLS'. Basically, I want to know What advantage one would have when regressing over 'Returns' and Not Prices. Returns are essentially driven by prices. So, what's the specific need to do so?

Comment: This is a question about regression. Just because it applies to stock prices i'm not sure it should be here.. in fact there is already an answer to this exact question on [cross validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/94727/97735) and they give a link to a presentation describing exactly the problem you can face from using regression on non stationary time series'.

Comment: @will That's exactly the reason I asked this to be moved to stats.stackexchange. The community felt otherwise. Anyways, thanks for the reference on crossValidated. Will check and revert back. I feel, this should still be migrated to stats.stackexchange.

Comment: The key issue is "spurious regression" which is mentioned and explained in the cross validated posts linked by will.